# Invalid XPath expression error in Selenium (with a valid XPath expression)

Tags: python, testing, xpath, selenium, pyccuracy

I'm testing a Python application using [pyccuracy](https://github.com/heynemann/pyccuracy/wiki/), which has a Selenium driver.

My test results are presenting some instability issues with XPath expressions. Sometimes I get an "Invalid XPath" error, with a valid XPath expression. If I run the test again, it may work. I've followed the stack trace, but I couldn't find a solution for that.

**Stack trace:**

```
I do not see "top-search-tag-name" element - FAILED - Error executing action <bound method ElementIsNotVisibleAction.execute of <pyccuracy.actions.core.element_actions.ElementIsNotVisibleAction object at 0x2283b10>> - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/env_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyccuracy/fixture_items.py", line 99, in execute
    self.execute_function(context, *self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/workspace/env_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyccuracy/actions/core/element_actions.py", line 179, in execute
    self.assert_element_is_not_visible(context, element_key, error_message)
  File "/workspace/env_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyccuracy/actions/__init__.py", line 147, in assert_element_is_not_visible
    if self.is_element_visible(context, selector):
  File "/workspace/env_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyccuracy/actions/__init__.py", line 139, in is_element_visible
    is_visible = context.browser_driver.is_element_visible(selector)
  File "/workspace/env_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyccuracy/drivers/core/selenium_driver.py", line 86, in is_element_visible
    is_present = self.selenium.is_element_present(element_selector)
  File "/workspace/env_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 1369, in is_element_present
    return self.get_boolean("isElementPresent", [locator,])
  File "/workspace/env_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 261, in get_boolean
    boolstr = self.get_string(verb, args)
  File "/workspace/env_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 223, in get_string
    result = self.do_command(verb, args)
  File "/workspace/env_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 217, in do_command
    raise Exception, data
Exception: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]: //form[@id='searchtop']//ul[@class = 'tags block editing']//li/a[@class = 'tag']
```

**HTML code (cleaned up)**

```html
<form id="searchtop">
  <ul class="tags block editing">
    <li class="tag">
      <a href="#" class="tag">Section Label</a>
      <a href="#" class="remove" title="Remove filter"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ...
</form>
```

In this test, I've clicked the remove filter link and then checked if the element is not present. The XPath expression is correct. In Chrome, for instance, I get the element selected with $x(...), before removing the tag, and get an empty list after removing it. Which is what the test does. Sometimes the same test runs without errors, in the exact same environment.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What code? The pyccuracy code and xPath are present in the Stacktrace.

Comment: Post a sample of the HTML you are using. Giving us a blind XPath locator without the HTML it is being run against is useless. With that said, it is probably an issue regarding the element not being instantly present on the page, have you tried looking into WebDriverWait? Have you tried using another locator and seeing if you get the same behaviour? (a CSS selector would work well here I imagine)

Comment: If an element is not present it shouldn't give the invalid xpath[2] error I think.. Technically, there is something wrong in the xpath formation.. I am not able to figure out what.. Can you try debugging the xpath by removing the elements from end one by one.. Like try //form[@id='searchtop']//ul[@class = 'tags block editing']//li first then without li.. This will help you findout where exactly is the problem..

Comment: I've updated the post with more information. I think the problem is not about the waiting time because it raises the invalid xpath error (The exception should be another, I think).
It's hard debugging because the failure cannot be reproduced as I want it to.

Comment: Gabriel, you got any solutions for this ?

Comment: Kind of, I think this problem was caused because sometimes we get an element from the DOM and then check the visibility of it . If the element is removed (via JS, for instance), selenium RC throws this exception and pycurracy does not treat properly. At least, the same has ocurred in splinter, but throwing the right exception. I've written a new driver for pyccuracy using splinter and fixed it, although there were still some other instability issues and, almost always, I just find another way to test it.

Comment: you should try using curl on URL to see exactly what gets returned.  In my case it so happened that the initial response just loaded a 'bootstrap' which further retrieved the form and added DOM elements using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here:

2. Your test seems to continue to run even though there's an error
3. You're not waiting for the element before executing the next command.

> I do not see "top-search-tag-name" element - FAILED - Error executing

This error means.. the element "top-search-tag-name" is not present. It usually happens when the application is too slow or not fully loaded. To fix this, try to wait for the element before continuing.

> Exception: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]: //form[@id='searchtop']//ul[@class = 'tags block editing']//li/a[@class = 'tag']

The XPath expression seems to be valid. You may change the XPath expression to be shorter.

`//form[@id='searchtop']//[a.='Section Label']`